# How to view index.php via VirtualBox via Docker in browser?

Tags: docker

I'am learning docker and start test simple project contains only index.php, but it not work.

I start docker in VirtualBox(CentOS) on my Windows OS.

I have index.php

```
<?php
echo "Hello world";
```

I have Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0-apache  
COPY . /var/www/html
```

Then build image and start container:

```
docker build -t php-app .
docker run php-app
```

When I start container I see its ip

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.4.
```

In VirtualBox I can see index.php using

```
curl 172.17.0.4/index.php
```

But in my Windows OS I type 192.168.1.194 (VirtualBox ip) in browser and I don't see my index.php. Apparently problem in ports. But what should I change to see index.php in Docker via my Windows browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose your port.

Run the container with this command:

```
docker run -p 80:80 php-app
```

This way your container's 80 port which is where your Apache instance is listening, will be bound to your host's (your virtual box vm in this case) 80 port and you should be able to reach it from outside.

You can read docker's all command line options' documentation in the official page here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#pid-equivalent

Comment: I stop my local nginx in VirtualBox, which interrupt 80 port. Then run this command. Now I can access my index.php via browser. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to keep your nginx running you can specify a different port to the -p flag. For instance `-p 8080:80` will bind on port 8080 in the host network